# Is the late bus service from Val-d'Isère to Tignes running?

Tags: france, buses, skiing

Piste maps for Tignes and Val-d'Isère included a [timetable](http://public.tignes.net/TIGNES.NET/PLAN_DES_PISTES_HIVER2015_2016.pdf) of buses from Val-d'Isère to Tignes for skiers who have missed the last ski lift back between the resorts: *If you succeed in missing the last ski lift you can still use the shuttle bus between the two resorts*.

[This review](http://www.onthesnow.co.uk/news/a/105706/espace-killy--one-ski-area--two-very-different-resorts) also contains the sentence: *If you succeed in missing the last ski lift you can still use the shuttle bus between the two resorts.* However, a [piste map for this season (2016/17)](http://public.tignes.net/PLANDESPISTES/plan_des_pistes.pdf) does not contain any reference to such a bus.

Does anyone know if the service is still running or will begin running for the upcoming season, and if the timetable has changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just got back from my holiday in Tignes and while there asked this question at the tourist office. They confirmed that the service is still running but has a new timetable which I have included below:

Tignes -> Val d'Isere

```
Tignes le Lac                08:50    10:30    17:00    18:10    19:20

Tignes les Boisses             -        -      17:08    18:18    19:28

Val d'Isere La Daille        09:18    10:58    17:28    18:38    19:48

Val d'Isere Gare Routiere    09:20    11:00    17:30    18:40    19:50
```

Val d'Isere -> Tignes

```
Val d'Isere Gare Routiere    09:10    12:45    16:25    16:45    17:35    18:45    19:55

Val d'Isere La Daille        09:12    12:47    16:27      -      17:37    18:47    19:57

Tignes les Boisses             -        -      16:47      -      17:57    19:07    20:17

Tignes le Lac                09:35    13:10    16:55    17:10    18:05    19:15    20:25
```

The daytime services run on weekdays only, with the last 3 services a day running 7 days a week. I was advised that the current arangement is that this service runs during the winter season only, which this year is considered to be from the 26.11.2016 to 01.05.2017. The fare is 6.30eur (reduced to 5.40eur for under 26) each way. While I did not use the service in the end, I did see them many times, they appear to be operated by coaches which had Tignes -> Val d'Isere shuttle painted in red on the side. I also observed people placing skis in the luggage compartment underneath the coach.